# Is it possible to enable USB Debugging (Install via USB) on Redmi phone without signing into Xiaomi account?

Tags: usb-debugging, xiaomi, developer-options, redmi, development

I am trying to debug an android app using my Redmi S2 phone (android 8.1) but there is a problem. Even though I can enable USB Debugging in developer options, I am unable to enable "Install via USB" option. It asks for a Xiaomi account which I don't have (and don't want to open).

As per [this one year old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/a87al5/enable_install_via_usb_without_signing_in_to/), its possible but not without rooting. Mine is a relatively new phone and I don't want to root it just yet. Is there any other trivial way to enable the *Install via USB* option?

**EDIT**

My question differs from the linked one in that I don't want to root my phone or sign into a Mi Account to enable "install via USB". I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve these workarounds.

Comment: Looks like there was [a new answer on the duplicate](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/229242/44325) not requiring rooting nor sign in. Consider checking that, or otherwise following that question to be notified for future answers.

Comment: @AndrewT thanks for the inputs. I tried but that solution didn't work for my phone, I'll follow that thread for future posts.